# Error while calling web service, operation can not be completed

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, nsurlrequest

I am call web-service and I am getting 0 bytes in response as well as getting error like below:

> Error Domain=kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork Code=303 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork error 303.)" UserInfo=0xa9b8ef0 {NSErrorFailingURLKey=http://quantuminfoways.com/crossfit_wodgenius/webservice/sync.php, NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=http://quantuminfoways.com/crossfit_wodgenius/webservice/sync.php}

And i am passing data as the
[sample link](http://quantuminfoways.com/crossfit_wodgenius/webservice/sync.php?udid=123&new=yes&uid=45&data=%7B%7D).

And in data i am passing this:

```
{
    createwod =     {
        deletedcreatewod =         (
        );
        newcreatewod =         (
        );
    };
    favorite =     {
        deletedfavorite =         (
        );
        newfavorite =         (
        );
    };
    gym =     {
        deletedgym =         (
        );
        newgym =         (
        );
    };
    workoutlog =     {
        deletedworkoutlog =         (
        );
        deletedworkoutlogtime =         (
        );
        newworkoutlog =         (
        );
    };
}
```

Can any one help me to solve it?

thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [what is kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork Code=303](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25077284/what-is-kcferrordomaincfnetwork-code-303)

Answer (score 0):

One of the reason of error "kcferrordomaincfnetwork error 303" when you are calling a POST method as GET.

Answer (score -2):

A 303 error is a redirect error.

You might want to check out the automatic handling of redirects with NSURLConnection:
https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/URLLoadingSystem/Articles/RequestChanges.html

If you'd like to handle it manually, the redirect url is in the response's 'Location' header. Here's how you can grab it in your connection:didReceiveResponse delegate method.

```
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response {
    NSHTTPURLResponse *httpResponse = (NSHTTPURLResponse*)response;
    // ... if the response status is 303 ...
    if ([response respondsToSelector:@selector(allHeaderFields)]) {
        NSString* location = [[httpResponse allHeaderFields] valueForKey:@"Location"];
            // do whatever with the redirect url 
    }
}
```

You coul also try urlEncoding your url including the data. Try what happens if you just call the following URL: http://quantuminfoways.com/crossfit_wodgenius/webservice/sync.php?udid=123&new=yes&uid=45&data=%20%7B%20createwod%20=%20%7B%20deletedcreatewod%20=%20(%20);%20newcreatewod%20=%20(%20);%20%7D;%20favorite%20=%20%7B%20deletedfavorite%20=%20(%20);%20newfavorite%20=%20(%20);%20%7D;%20gym%20=%20%7B%20deletedgym%20=%20(%20);%20newgym%20=%20(%20);%20%7D;%20workoutlog%20=%20%7B%20deletedworkoutlog%20=%20(%20);%20deletedworkoutlogtime%20=%20(%20);%20newworkoutlog%20=%20(%20);%20%7D;%20%7D

Comment: The OP gets an error of type `kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork` which is different from HTT status codes. Error 303 is a  `kCFErrorHTTPParseFailure` which means, that the client couldn't handle the result properly.

Comment: i am getting proper result in browser. but not in mobile.